# Bullets in Indesign page numbers - how to get rid of?

Tags: adobe, adobe-indesign

For some odd reason I have gotten bullets in my page numbers, how do I get rid of those?

[image: Page number with bullet]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your page number. And go to here:

[image]

Then chose the List Type 'None':

[image]

Comment: I cannot select them - seems not to have a select marking when I click them - feel a bit stupid :|

Comment: I'm sure these page numbers lay on some of the 'master' pages. You have to jump on the respective master page first. And make sure the layer isn't locked.

Comment: And then I managed (ctrl+shift+click to edit parent) - thank you